# Check if Reactive form value is changed from initial

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a reactive form with 3 controls in it, I want to detect changes of the form. I have created a value change method of the form and subscribed to it but. Right now every time any of it's control value is changing the event is emitting.

If user has added any value to ant of this 3 controls and trying to exit the page, then I want to promt a modal that there is unsaved changes in the form.

**How can I be able to check the emitted value on change of the form is different than it's initial value?**

```
public createGroupForm : FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  this.createGroupForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      groupName: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      groupPrivacy: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      groupTagline: new FormControl('')
  });

  this.onCreateGroupFormValueChange();
}


onCreateGroupFormValueChange(){
    this.createGroupForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
      //emitting every time if any control value is changed
    });
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you must each time your subscribe is emitted check the form value with initial value
and use hasChange when ever you want

```
public createGroupForm : FormGroup;
hasChange: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this.createGroupForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      groupName: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      groupPrivacy: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      groupTagline: new FormControl('')
  });

  this.onCreateGroupFormValueChange();
}


onCreateGroupFormValueChange(){
    const initialValue = this.createGroupForm.value
    this.createGroupForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.hasChange = Object.keys(initialValue).some(key => this.form.value[key] != 
                        initialValue[key])
    });
}
```

Comment: what about if we need to populate the form with values first and after that we need to listen for changes?

Comment: Initially checkbox is checked and this.hasChange is "false", now when I uncheck it and check it back, this.hasChange value remains "true"

Comment: What do you mean by "this.form.value[key]"? I mean which form is meant?

Comment: This will work only for simple, "flat" forms, without nested formgroups or formarrays. For more complex forms, that equality operator in the `some` will not cut it, you need something better like the lodash `isEqual()`.

Answer (score 2):

No need to subscribe, just check it on demand when the user is leaving:

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  newUserForm!: FormGroup;
  initialFormValues!: User;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      ,
    });
    this.initialFormValues = this.newUserForm.value;
  }

  formHasChanged(): boolean {
    return Object.entries(this.initialFormValues).some(
      ([field, value]) => value !== this.newUserForm.value[field]
    );
  }

  exitPage() {
    if (this.formHasChanged()) {
      // Open modal
    } else {
      // Redirect user
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use ngOnDestroy life cycle hook method and then in that method check if the current value is different from initial value , then open the modal ....

```
@Component({ selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...` })
class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
    public createGroupForm: FormGroup;
    public initalValues;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createGroupForm = this._formBuilder.group({
            groupName: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
            groupPrivacy: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
            groupTagline: new FormControl('')
        });
        this.initalValues = this.createGroupForm.value;
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.initalValues != this.createGroupForm.value) {
            //open modal
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxjs operators to check values.

```
 import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, FormArray, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';  
import { pairwise, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.createGroupForm.valueChanges
      .pipe(startWith(''), pairwise())
      .subscribe(([prev, cur]) => {
        console.log('example 1 prev val', prev);
        console.log('example 1 cur val', cur);
        console.log('---');

        if (confirm('value will be changed')) {
          console.log('value changed')
        } else {
          console.log('value not changed')
        }
```

Comment: what is this function you have written in if clause confirm()? Can you please explain.

Comment: @RAHULKUNDU It shows the alert with this you can set message like "you have some unsaved changes" with two buttons Ok and cancel. If a user wants to save those latest changes then it will go in the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to subscribe to form.valueChanges :

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash';

public createGroupForm : FormGroup;
hasChange: boolean = false;

private readonly destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);

ngOnInit() {
  this.createGroupForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      groupName: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      groupPrivacy: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      groupTagline: new FormControl('')
  });

  this.onCreateGroupFormValueChange();
}


onCreateGroupFormValueChange(){
    const initialValue = this.createGroupForm.value
    this.createGroupForm.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)).subscribe(
        formWithChanges => this.hasChange = !isEqual(initialValue , formWithChanges))
      )
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the `dirty` check when exiting the page like this

```
if(this.createGroupForm.get('groupName').dirty || 
 this.createGroupForm.get('groupPrivacy').dirty || 
 this.createGroupForm.get('groupTagline').dirty) {
   // make an alert for unsaved changes
}
```

Comment: dirty become true when the  value changes , so it does not check changes from initial value .